# How do I add all waypoints from a point to point googlemaps to a database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I am playing some with google waypoints
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints

Can't figure out how to get results to load into a database.

I wish to query these.

Answer (score 0):

```
function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  var waypts = [];
  var checkboxArray = document.getElementById('waypoints');

// These three variables are to be stored in DB, use Jquery GET/POST to a php and store it to a database
  }
```

[Check here for POST](http://www.askaboutphp.com/213/php-and-jquery-submit-a-form-without-refreshing-the-page.html)